# Using Softmax Activation function after calculating loss from BCEWithLogitLoss (Binary Cross Entropy + Sigmoid activation)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am going through a Binary Classification tutorial using `PyTorch` and here, the last layer of the network is `torch.Linear()`  with just one neuron. (Makes Sense) which will give us a single neuron.  as `pred=network(input_batch)`

After that the choice of Loss function is `loss_fn=BCEWithLogitsLoss()`  (which is numerically stable than using the softmax first and then calculating loss) which will apply `Softmax` function to the output of last layer to give us a probability.  so after that, it'll calculate the binary cross entropy to minimize the loss.

`loss=loss_fn(pred,true)`

My concern is that after all this, the author used `torch.round(torch.sigmoid(pred))`

Why would that be? I mean I know it'll get the prediction probabilities in the range `[0,1]` and then round of the values with default threshold of 0.5.

Isn't it better to use the `sigmoid` once after the last layer within the network rather using a softmax and a sigmoid at 2 different places given it's a binary classification??

Wouldn't it be better to just

```
out = self.linear(batch_tensor)
return self.sigmoid(out)
```

and then calculate the `BCE` loss and use the `argmax()` for checking accuracy??

I am just curious that can it be a valid strategy?

Comment: What's the tutorial you are following? Why not simply include a link?

Comment: No, `BCEWithLogitsLoss` does not apply a softmax. It applies a sigmoid to the logits followed by binary cross-entropy. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bcewithlogitsloss

Comment: It's a paid video from PluralSight. Sorry I was confused between bianary and Multi-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be thinking of the binary classification as a multi-class classification with two classes, but that is not quite correct when using the binary cross-entropy approach. Let's start by clarifying the goal of the binary classification before looking at any implementation details.

Technically, there are two classes, 0 and 1, but instead of considering them as two separate classes, you can see them as opposites of each other. For example, you want to classify whether a StackOverflow answer was helpful or not. The two classes would be *"helpful"* and *"not helpful"*. Naturally, you would simply ask *"Was the answer helpful?"*, the negative aspect is left off, and if that wasn't the case, you could deduce that it was *"not helpful"*. (Remember, it's a binary case, there is no middle ground).

Therefore, your model only needs to predict a single class, but to avoid confusion with the actual two classes, that can be expressed as: The model predicts the probability that the positive case occurs. In context of the previous example: *What is the probability that the StackOverflow answer was helpful?*

Sigmoid gives you values in the range *[0, 1]*, which are the probabilities. Now you need to decide when the model is confident enough for it to be positive by defining a threshold. To make it balanced, the threshold is 0.5, therefore as long as the probability is greater than 0.5 it is positive (class 1: *"helpful*") otherwise it's negative (class 0: *"not helpful"*), which is achieved by rounding (i.e. `torch.round(torch.sigmoid(pred))`).

> After that the choice of Loss function is `loss_fn=BCEWithLogitsLoss()` (which is numerically stable than using the softmax first and then calculating loss) which will apply `Softmax` function to the output of last layer to give us a probability.
>
> Isn't it better to use the sigmoid once after the last layer within the network rather using a softmax and a sigmoid at 2 different places given it's a binary classification??

`BCEWithLogitsLoss` applies *Sigmoid* not Softmax, there is no Softmax involved at all. From the [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss):

> This loss combines a *Sigmoid* layer and the *BCELoss* in one single class. This version is more numerically stable than using a plain *Sigmoid* followed by a *BCELoss* as, by combining the operations into one layer, we take advantage of the log-sum-exp trick for numerical stability.

By not applying Sigmoid in the model you get a more numerically stable version of the binary cross-entropy, but that means you have to apply the Sigmoid manually if you want to make an actual prediction outside of training.

> [...] and use the `argmax()` for checking accuracy??

Again, you're thinking of the multi-class scenario. You only have a single output class, i.e. output has size *[batch_size, 1]*. Taking argmax of that, will always give you 0, because that is the only available class.

Comment: Oh!!! Got it. Thank you. I was confused at the time because I was not thinking clearly.